# SDL RenderClear transparency

Tags: c#, c++, sdl, sdl-2

I had a question, for some reason, when I run the code below the window is turning black (alpha is 0 so it should be transparent), any ideas?

NOTE: This is written on a c# using a binding of a c++ SDL library

```
renderer = SDL.SDL_CreateRenderer(sdlWindow, -1, SDL.SDL_RendererFlags.SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL.SDL_RendererFlags.SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

SDL.SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL.SDL_BlendMode.SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

...

SDL.SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SDL.SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL.SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

Comment: Was the window (on which the code renders) created with an alpha channel?  There are possibly two different alphas channels here: the alpha channel for composing onto the the window and the alpha channel of the window itself.

Comment: this is the initialization of a window - ```sdlWindow = SDL.SDL_CreateWindow(String.Empty, 0, 0, this.sdlPanel.Size.Width, this.sdlPanel.Size.Height, SDL.SDL_WindowFlags.SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS);```

Comment: SDL doesn't support window transparency.